# From form to sql query

Tags: magento-1.8, adminhtml, magento-community, adminform

I've got this new tab:

```
<?php
class Pulsestorm_Adminhello_AdminhelloController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        //Get current layout state 
        $this->loadLayout();    

        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
            'my_block_name_here',
            array('template' => 'activecodeline/developer.phtml')
        );

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

        //Release layout stream
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
?>
```

And my developer.phtml is like this:

```
<p>Selecione uma opção e preencha os campos necessários:</p>
<form action="bla.php" method="post">
    <select name="dia">
        <option>- Dia -</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>
    <select name="mes">
        <option>- Mês -</option>
        <option value="1">Janeiro</option>
        <option value="2">Fevereiro</option>
        <option value="3">Março</option>
        <option value="4">Abril</option>
        <option value="5">Maio</option>
        <option value="6">Junho</option>
        <option value="7">Julho</option>
        <option value="8">Agosto</option>
        <option value="9">Setembro</option>
        <option value="10">Outubro</option>
        <option value="11">Novembro</option>
        <option value="12">Dezembro</option>
    </select>
    Ano: <input type="text" name="ano" maxlength="4" style="width:30px"><br>
    Trimestre:
    <select name="trimestre">
        <option value="primeiro">1</option>
        <option value="segundo">2</option>
        <option value="terceiro">3</option>
        <option value="quarto">4</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="dia">Dia<br>
    <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="mes">Mês<br>
    <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="trimestre">Trimestre<br>
    <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="Ano">Ano<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How can I get the values from the form and make a query ?

If I add this to the `Pulsestorm_Adminhello_AdminhelloController`:

```
public function resultAction(){

    var_dump($this->getRequest()->getPost());

}
```

and edit the form to this:

```
<?php
$path = 'adminhtml/Adminhello/index/result';
?>
<p>Selecione uma opção e preencha os campos necessários:</p>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl($path); ?>" method="post">
…
```

If I do that, after I submit the form I'm redirect to the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

The action of your form can be constructed using `<?php echo $this->getUrl($path); ?>`.

The `$path` depends on your configuration, but I guess it is: `adminhtml/Adminhello/index`.

Comment: So something like <?php $path = 'adminhtml/Adminhello/index/result'; ?> <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl($path); ?>">. And creating a new controller maybe (public function resultAction()) ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `action` of your custom form. You need to form like this.

```
 <form action="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('[frontend_name]/adminhello/result')" name="some_name" id="some_id">
 </form>
```

Where `frontendname` comes from your `config.xml` file. You need to use frontendname that is configured under `route` node. But your class name indicates that, your module tries to extend magento admin section. If that is the case frontendname is none another than fronendname for admin. Normally it would be `admin` or `adminhtml`, depending upon the value that you configured while you install Magento.

After this, you need to create a new method inside your controller class. It should somewhat looks like

```
public function resultAction(){

    var_dump($this->getRequest()->getPost());

}
```

I hope that would solve your problem

[*This answer is a part of #mageStackDay. It is an event conducted by Magento Community members as part of increasing the question-answer ratio. For more information http://www.magestackday.com/*]

Answer (score 0):

Add a new action on your controller:

```
public function processAction()
{
        // Here you have access to $this->getRequest()->getPost()
}
```

then set your form's action to this action.

Comment: And what would be the 'action' and the 'method' on the form ?

Comment: The `indexAction` doesn't need a param because it's the index action (`yoursite.com/module/controller/action`) - So in this case, the `processAction` would have the path `yoursite.com/adminhello/adminhello/process`.